# How to pass model to controller action using ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im using ajax call to pass model data in to my controller action , but controller receives empty model when I call via ajax ,
Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit( int id, ALDS.Web.Areas.Direct2M3.Models.ItemInputModel collection)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add update logic here
        return View("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And here is my input model

```
public class ItemInputModel
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Buyer Code")]
    public string ModelCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("BOM Description")]
    public string BOMDescription { get; set; }
    //BUYER CODE
    [DisplayName("UOM")]
    public string UOM { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Alternative UOM")]
    public string AltUOM { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Garment Color Wise")]
    public string ColorWise { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Garment Size Wise")]
    public string SizeWise { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("RM Color Wise")]
    public string RMcolorWise { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("RM Size Wise")]
    public string RMsize { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Procument Group")]
    public string BrandixProcurementGroupCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Designation CPT")]
    public string DesignationCPT { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Item Name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Fabric Composition")]
    public string FabricComposition { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Hierachy Code ")]
    public string HierarchyCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("GSM Value")]
    public string GSMValue { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("RM Width")]
    public string RMWidth { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ajax call from the view

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    url: '/ItemMaster/Edit',
    data:{ id: collection.ID, collection:collection},
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("ok");
        //Do Stuff 
        //$("#DailyInvoiceItems").html(data.Id);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Failed');
        //Do Stuff or Nothing
    }
});
```

and im using this model to pass to the action from the , ajax

```
var model = {
    ID: $('#ID').val(),
    ModelCode: $('#txtModelCode').val(),
    BOMDescription: $('#txtBOMDescription').val(),
    UOM: $('#txtUOM').val(),
    AltUOM: $('#txtAltUOM').val(),
    ColorWise: $('#ddnColorWise').val(),
    SizeWise: $('#ddnSizeWise').val(),
    RMcolorWise: $('#ddnRMcolorWise').val(),
    RMsize: $('#ddnRMsize').val(),
    BrandixProcurementGroupCode: $('#ddnBrandixProcurementGroupCode').val(),
    DesignationCPT: $('#txtDesignationCPT').val(),
    ItemName: $('#txtItemName').val(),
    FabricComposition: $('#txtFabricComposition').val(),
    HierarchyCode: $('#txtHierarchyCode').val(),
    GSMValue: $('#txtGSMValue').val(),
    RMWidth: $('#txtRMWidth').val()
};
```

I put a break point inside the action method and inspect the collection parameter but it is an empty input object , with null properties !
Can anyone help me????
Thankz,.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringfy({ id: collection.ID, collection:collection}),`

Comment: But you can just use `$('form).serialize()` to correctly serialize your form and reduce your whole script to a couple of lines. And why are you sending the ID value twice? But is its really `var model = { ...`, then it would need to be `collection: model` not `collection: collection`

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry for the mistake,ajax call is in separate function  and I pass the model to that function , inside that function model is assigned to the collection,

Comment: I tried JSON.stringfy() but no luck , I don't know it always fails,..

Comment: And its `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` (not `dataType`). But why are yout writing all this code to do something that can be done in a couple of lines of code

Comment: did you mean $('form).serialize()  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134937/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-roshan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of errors with ajax code. First your method returns html (a view - although it should be a partial view) so it need to be `dataType: 'html'`, or you can omit it altogether. Second because your sending an object containing objects, you would need to stringify the data (using `data: JSON.stringify({ id: collection.ID, collection: model}),` and add the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option (note the name of your javascript object is `model`, not `collection`.

However most of this code is unnecessary. Your model already contains a property `long ID` so there is no need to post and bind it twice and you controller method can be just

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ItemInputModel model)
{
    ....
    return PartialView(..), // not View(..)
}
```

Assuming you have generated your form controls correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods, for example

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelCode)
....
```

then you can use the `.serialize()` method to correctly serialize all the form controls, so that your ajax becomes

```
var data = $('form').serialize(); // or use the id of the form is you have given it one
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html', // this can be omitted - the ajax() function will work it out
    cache: false,
    url: '/ItemMaster/Edit',
    data: data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ... // append the partial view you return to the DOM?
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Side note: You should always use `Url.Action()` to generate the correct url's, for example `url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "ItemMaster")',`. If this script is in an external file, then generate it in the main view (e.g. as a `data-*` attribute an the button element your handling) and pass it to the function.

Comment: When I use that ajax call that returns status code 500 ok but call error function , when I use Json.stringfy() the status is ok bit no data posted, to the controller , why is that?

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means your controller method is throwing an exception - you need to debug your code (and you can also use your browser tools - the Network tab to inspect the response which will contain details of the error)