# Trying to pass a list of models from a table through viewmodel back to controller but it's always coming in null?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have been having an issue where one field of my ViewModel is being passed back as null when I try to send it back to the controller. I have a ViewModel file that is set up like so:

```
 public class vmSCUMaster
    {
        public List<LockerDoorMaster> lockers { get; set; }
        public long? masterID { get; set; }
        public string masterName { get; set; }
    }
```

So far, when I first pass this ViewModel to the View, lockers (the list) is not null and the page renders the correct data. When I submit the form from the View, however, lockers is always null. The masterID and masterName are sent back to the controller just fine. In the View, I am displaying the content of lockers in a table, and the user has the option to add more items to the table. I want these added items also appended to the list of lockers when passed back to the controller. Here is my code in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SCUMaster", new { area = "Branch" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmSCU", @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.masterID)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title" style="display: inline;">Lockers</h4>
    <div id="DivExport" class="pull-right"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#Add').modal('show');" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs pull-right launch-modal" data-id="0" data-title="Add" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</a>
</div>
    <div class="table-responsive" id="tblMaster">
        <table id="default-datatable" class="table table table-bordered nowrap" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hardware Name</th>
                <th>Display Name</th>
                <th>Door Type</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Enabled/Disabled</th>
                <th>ADA Compliant</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
        <tbody id="lockerDoors" class="form-group">
            @foreach (var item in Model.lockers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockerDoorMasterID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.LockerDoorNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control DisplayName" } })
                    </td>
                    <td class="DoorType">
                         @if (item.DoorType == 1)
                         {
                             <select>
                                 <option value="1" selected="selected">Customer</option>
                                 <option value="2">Merchant</option>
                             </select>
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             <select>
                                 <option value="1">Customer</option>
                                 <option value="2" selected="selected">Merchant</option>
                             </select>
                         }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockerDoorStatu.LockerDoorStatusName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control Status" } })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control IsEnabled" } })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsADA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control IsADA" } })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <label id="btnSave" type="submit" onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</label>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SCUMaster")" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my script that dynamically adds items to my table:

```
function test() {
            $('#Add').modal('hide');
            var num = $("#number").val();
            var type = $("#type").val();
            var table = document.getElementById("lockers");
            if (num > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
                    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var element1 = document.createElement("div");
                    element1.className = "form-group HardwareID"; 
                    cell1.appendChild(element1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount + 1; 

                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
                    element2.type = "text";
                    element2.className = "form-group DisplayName";
                    element2.defaultValue = rowCount + 1; 
                    cell2.appendChild(element2);

                    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                    var element3 = document.createElement("select");
                    if (type == 1) {
                        element3.innerHTML = "<option value='1' selected='selected'>Customer</option> <option value = '2'> Merchant</option>"
                    }
                    else {
                        element3.innerHTML = "<option value='1'>Customer</option> <option value = '2' selected='selected'> Merchant</option>"
                    }
                    element3.className = "form-group DoorType";
                    cell3.appendChild(element3);

                    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                    var element4 = document.createElement("div");
                    element4.className = "form-group Status";
                    cell4.appendChild(element4);
                    cell4.innerHTML = "Closed"; 

                    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
                    element5.className = "form-group IsEnabled"; 
                    element5.type = "checkbox"; 
                    cell5.appendChild(element5);

                    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5); 
                    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
                    element6.className = "form-group IsADA"; 
                    element6.type = "checkbox"; 
                    cell6.appendChild(element6);
                }
            }
        }
```

Right now I am just trying to submit by calling the regular form submit() function. I have tried to pass this in with jquery/ajax as well, but this hasn't worked either. Here was what I attempted to do:

```
function submit() {
            var indexUrl = "/Branch/SCUMaster/Create";
            var list = [];
            $('#tblMaster tbody tr').each(function (index, ele) {
                var LockerDoorMaster = {
                    DoorType: $('.DoorType', this).val(),
                    LockerDoorStatus: 2,
                    IsActive: $('.IsEnabled', this).is(':checked'),
                    LockerDoorNumber: $('.DisplayName', this).val(),
                    LockerDoorMasterID: $('.HardwareID', this).val()
                }
                list.push(LockerDoorMaster);
            });
            var data = {
                masterID: $('#masterID').val(),
                masterName: $('#masterName').val(),
                lockers: list
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: indexUrl,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Message == "Error") {
                        warningMessage("Some thing went wrong please try again");
                    }
                    else if (result.Message == "success") {
                        window.location.href = window.location.href + "#save";
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    warningMessage("Some thing went wrong please try again");
                }
            });
        }
```

I apologize for this question being so long, and thank you in advance for all of your help! I have been stuck on this problem for days now so any help is appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go the jquery route, you can leverage the code that is already there.

After researching, I found this article: [pass-model-to-controller-action-using-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057340/how-to-pass-model-to-controller-action-using-ajax-call)

Using the mentioned [FromBody] attribute. I tested this with you current implementation and it seemed to resolve the issue immediately.

If that does not work, I also tested using $post syntax instead, which worked without the need to stringify.

```
$.post(indexUrl, data, function (response) {
//code to execute
});
```